# HTML5 Audio - currentTime value is always 0 on Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

HTML 5:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="http://SHOUTCAST_URL:PORT/;stream.mp3"></source>
</audio>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("audio").get(0).play();
setInterval(function() {
    alert($("audio").get(0).currentTime); // Always alerts 0
}, 1000);
```

This is a simple HTML5 Shoutcast Player. It alerts the current amount of elapsed time on Desktop but Android Chrome. What's wrong with Android?

Comment: maybe the server doesn't serve streaming?

Comment: It does and song plays.

Answer (score 0):

It was a known bug at Chromium, https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=327425, that was supposed to have been resolved. I've let them know it is still an issue, https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=584562 . My own audio app has the same problem.